# bad argument to internal function error in python

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a python script that uses ReportLab to create a report, the script has been tested and works as expected however on occasions I get the following error message

```
TraceBack info:

File "C:\tools\LegionellaTool.py", line 605, in <module>

createReport(selectedCoolingTowers, Report_outputs_folder, dbo_COLGIS, openPDF)

Error Info:

..\Objects\moduleobject.c:50: bad argument to internal function
```

Line 605 is `createReport(selectedCoolingTowers, Report_outputs_folder, dbo_COLGIS, openPDF)`

createReport is the function that ...creates the report. 
I have debugged through the code and I havent got any errors, what might make the error to appear, the error only happens on occasions whereas on other occasions the report is created fine.

**EDIT=====** createReport code

```
def createReport(myReportTable, myReportFolder, M3Table, OpenPDF):
    global Author
    global TimeStamp

##    myReportTable = gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
##    myReportFolder = gp.GetParameterAsText(1)
##    M3Table = gp.GetParameterAsText(2)
##    OpenPDF = gp.GetParameterAsText(3)

    Author = getpass.getuser() #gets OS user name
    TimeStamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().hour) + ':' + str(datetime.datetime.now().minute) + ' on the ' + str(datetime.date.today().day) + '/' + str(datetime.date.today().month) + '/' + str(datetime.date.today().year) 

    #add time stamp to file name
    myFile = myReportFolder + os.sep + 'CoolingTowersForInspection_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().hour) + '_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().minute) + '_' + str(datetime.date.today().day) + '_' + str(datetime.date.today().month) + '_' + str(datetime.date.today().year) + '.pdf'
    c = reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas(myFile)

    #creates sectors array
    sectors = []
    sectors.append('NW')
    sectors.append('NE')
    sectors.append('SW')
    sectors.append('SE')

    for sector in sectors:
        #sector header
        #framePage(c, 'Cooling Towers for Inspection - ' + sector + ' sector')
        title = 'Cooling Towers for Inspection - ' + sector + ' sector'
        c.setFont('Helvetica',20) #title font
        c.drawString(reportlab.lib.units.inch, 10.5 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, title) #creates title

        c.setFont('Helvetica',10) #header and footer font

        #creates header
        c.drawCentredString(4.135 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, 0.75 * reportlab.lib.units.inch,
                                 'Report generated by ' + Author + ' at ' + TimeStamp + ' - Page %d' % c.getPageNumber())

        #creates footer
        c.drawCentredString(4.135 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, 11.00 * reportlab.lib.units.inch,
                                'Environmental Services')

        #draw a border
        c.setStrokeColorRGB(1,0,0)
        c.setLineWidth(5)
        c.line(0.8 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, reportlab.lib.units.inch, 0.8 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, 10.75 * reportlab.lib.units.inch)

        #reset carefully afterwards
        c.setLineWidth(1)
        c.setStrokeColorRGB(0,0,0)

        c.setFont('Helvetica', 10)

        #gets towers in that sector
        myTowers = arcpy.SearchCursor(myReportTable,"\"SECTOR\" = '" + sector + "'","","")
        selTower = myTowers.next()

        y = 730

        if selTower is not None:

            while selTower:
                #insert page break when close to the end of the page
                if y < 110:
                    c.showPage()
                    y = 730
                    framePage(c, 'Cooling Towers for Inspection - ' + sector + ' sector')

                if selTower.TOWER_NAME <> None:
                    c.drawString(100, y, string.strip(selTower.TOWER_NAME))
                else:
                    c.drawString(100, y, "na")
                y = y - 12

                if selTower.TOWER_ADDRESS <> None:
                    c.drawString(100, y, string.strip(selTower.TOWER_ADDRESS))
                else:
                    c.drawString(100, y, "na")
                y = y - 12

                c.drawString(100, y, "Number of towers: " + str(int(selTower.NUMBER_OF_TOWERS)) + " ;   M3 Code: " + selTower.UKEY + " ;   Distance band: " + str(int(selTower.distance)) + " meters")
                y = y - 12

                inspectString = ""
                if selTower.TOWER_RATING <> None:
                    inspectString = "Inspection rating: " + selTower.TOWER_RATING
                else:
                    inspectString = "Inspection rating: na;"

                if selTower.TOWER_LAST_INSPECTION <> None:
                    t = selTower.TOWER_LAST_INSPECTION
                    strLastInspection = t.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y")

                    inspectString = inspectString + "   Last inspection: " + strLastInspection
                    #inspectString = inspectString + "   Last inspection: " + selTower.TOWER_LAST_INSPECTION
                else:
                    inspectString = inspectString + "   Last inspection: na"

                c.drawString(100, y, inspectString)
                y = y - 12

                c.drawString(100, y, "Contacts:")
                y = y - 12

                myTowerUKEY = selTower.UKEY

                #gets contacts for that cooling tower            
                myTowerContacts = arcpy.SearchCursor(M3Table,"\"UKEY\" = '" + myTowerUKEY + "'","","")

                selContact = myTowerContacts.next()

                while selContact:
                    if y < 110:
                        c.showPage()
                        y = 730
                        framePage(c, 'Cooling Towers for Inspection - ' + sector + ' sector')

                    contact = ""
                    if selContact.TITLE <> None:
                        if string.strip(selContact.TITLE) <> "":
                            contact = string.strip(selContact.TITLE) + " "
                    if selContact.FIRSTNAME <> None:
                        contact = contact + selContact.FIRSTNAME + " "
                    if selContact.FAMILYNAME <> None:
                        contact = contact + selContact.FAMILYNAME + " "
                    if selContact.JOBTITLE <> None:
                        contact = contact + "(" + selContact.JOBTITLE + ") "
                    if selContact.TELW <> None:
                        contact = contact + selContact.TELW + "(work) "
                    if selContact.MOBILE <> None:
                        if string.strip(selContact.MOBILE) <> "":
                            contact = contact + string.strip(selContact.MOBILE) + "(mobile) "
                    if selContact.TELH <> None:
                        if string.strip(selContact.TELH) <> "":
                            contact = contact + string.strip(selContact.TELH) + "(home)"

                    contact = string.strip(contact)

                    c.drawString(100, y, contact)
                    y = y - 12
                    selContact = myTowerContacts.next()                

                y = y - 12
                del myTowerContacts
                selTower = myTowers.next()
        else:
            c.drawString(100, y, "no cooling towers for inspection in this sector")

        c.showPage() #insert page break after each sector

    del myTowers

    c.save()

    if OpenPDF == "true":
        os.startfile(myFile)

#function that creates each page
def framePage(canvas, title):
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica',20) #title font
    canvas.drawString(reportlab.lib.units.inch, 10.5 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, title) #creates title

    canvas.setFont('Helvetica',10) #header and footer font

    #creates header
    canvas.drawCentredString(4.135 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, 0.75 * reportlab.lib.units.inch,
                             'Report generated by ' + Author + ' at ' + TimeStamp + ' - Page %d' % canvas.getPageNumber())

    #creates footer
    canvas.drawCentredString(4.135 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, 11.00 * reportlab.lib.units.inch,
                            'Environmental Services')

    #draw a border
    canvas.setStrokeColorRGB(1,0,0)
    canvas.setLineWidth(5)
    canvas.line(0.8 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, reportlab.lib.units.inch, 0.8 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, 10.75 * reportlab.lib.units.inch)

    #reset carefully afterwards
    canvas.setLineWidth(1)
    canvas.setStrokeColorRGB(0,0,0)
```

EDIT Number 2 *****

Full traceback is here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tools\LegionellaTool.py", line 613, in <module>
    createReport(selectedCoolingTowers, Report_outputs_folder, dbo_COLGIS, openPDF)

  File "C:\tools\LegionellaTool.py", line 120, in createReport

    c.drawString(reportlab.lib.units.inch, 10.5 * reportlab.lib.units.inch, title) #creates title

  File "c:\python26\arcgis10.0\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 1481, in drawString

    t.textLine(text)

  File "c:\python26\arcgis10.0\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\textobject.py", line 426, in textLine

    self._code.append('%s T*' % self._formatText(text))
  File "c:\python26\arcgis10.0\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\textobject.py", line 393, in _formatText

    for f, t in pdfmetrics.unicode2T1(text,[font]+font.substitutionFonts):
SystemError: ..\Objects\moduleobject.c:50: bad argument to internal function

<type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>: 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? And some code that we can have a look at?

Comment: @Paco, The code is run in an external program called ArcGIS, it calls the script, so i am unable to get the full stack trace. I have updated the original question with the create report code - its a bit long...

Comment: @Paco, full trace added to original question

Comment: I don't know reportlab at all, but you should try to debug it using pdb. Add this before the line that fails: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` Then, keep typing `s`, until you reach the last line of the stacktrace. Finally print the values of all the variables to see if something is wrong. If you find what's wrong, you can press `u` to go back up a level, and at this point you can check the variables again. Keep doing this until you reach the top

Comment: Hi, has this been fixed yet? I've had the same error when generating a pdf with ReportLab in a script called from ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, intermittent errors with ReportLab are most often caused by problems when trying to rendering text that may have something 'weird' in it, like unexpected characters for the character set or nulls. Looking through your code I didn't notice anything that would obviously cause the problem, but you might want to look into the possibility that something contains an unexpected value.

In particular, I'd take a look at the code dealing with `selContact` and see if any of its attributes are unexpectedly null or just not strings which could lead to the errors.

Without a full stack trace, it's hard to say something more specific.

**ETA**

Based on the now provided stack trace, looks like the problem must either be with something going into the `title` variable that you are trying to draw or with the font being used to draw the string. Looking at your code I don't notice any problems, though, and nothing that would suggest an intermittent problem with the part of the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: I've added a full trace in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This message drove me crazy for the past few weeks and I finally figured out 2 things that caused this error and how to fix them:

- as G Gordon Worley III suggested, if you try to build your report with incorrect elements, it may appear.

  **Fix:** find which element is corrupted or debug your program outside ArcGIS, you'll have more explicit error messages.
- if your Python installation is a bit messed up, it may appear. What happened for me is that I included the ReportLab files in the same folder as my script to make it easier to distribute. But I had also previously installed ReportLab in my Python installation folders. Somehow, that confused ArcGIS.

  **Fix:** remove the Python??/(ArcGIS??.?/)Lib/site-packages/reportlab folder so that your script only has one library option.

I hope that will help someone.